# How to get window.ethereum in web_sys()?

Tags: rust, yew, web-sys

In javascript to [connect metamask](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-connect-reactjs-with-metamask/) it uses window.ethereum

```js
    if (window.ethereum) {
  
      window.ethereum
        .request({ method: "eth_requestAccounts" })
        .then((res) => accountChangeHandler(res[0]));
    } else {
      alert("install metamask extension!!");
    }
```

How to do that in yew.rs?

```rust
      if web_sys::window().unwrap().ethereum {
            let eth = web_sys::window().unwrap().ethereum;
            log!(eth);

        } else {
            log!("install metamask extension!!");
        }
```

Code error: no field `ethereum` on type `Window`

Comment: Seems I need to use js binding https://github.com/yewstack/yew/blob/master/examples/js_callback/src/bindings.rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `etherum` is something created by some script you have somewhere and not a standard DOM property. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=ethereum)

`web-sys` is just a convience library created on top of `wasm-bindgen` that gives easier access to the DOM API.

Still you have several ways to get the `etherum` value:

1. Write some javascript using `wasm-bindgen` https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/wasm-bindgen/reference/js-snippets.html#using-inline_js
2. Use the javascript `Reflect`, you will need `js-sys` library for this, because web-sys has no binding for it for some reason. `js_sys::Reflect::get(&window, &"ethereum".into());`